# Visual Studio Notepad++ Sync Color Schemes

Tags: visual-studio, notepad++

Is there an easy way to sync the color scheme/theme between visual studio 2008/2010 and notepad++? I would like to have it so that I could point visual studio and notepad++ to the same document and maintain the styles just through that.

Comment: +1 This question interests me as well. This would be useful.

Comment: The ultimate goal would be to obviously throw this folder into dropbox and sync across all my computers.

Comment: Pretty sure VS and Notepad++ use completely different ways to define colour schemes, which would make your desired workflow impossible. But I won't bet my life on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am 99.9% sure you can't do it through opening a document, unless there is a way to define color scheme based on extension.  The only thing you can do is write a script that changes both .ini files.

Make a system call to run the script, in the beginning of document you are opening, so that when it compiles it changes the .ini files.

Comment: I was hoping there was a different way to do it but I guess not. I just can't believe someone else hasn't already made something.

Comment: http://www.shilony.net/2012/09/02/notepad-visual-studio-theme/